# Unable to get a simple sample of Handlebars to work

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I have a simple example with Handlebars, and I cannot get it to work! Please help. I am trying to get the google app engine guestbook to work with handlebars instead of jinja2

HTML/Template code is as follows:

```
  Hello {{user.nickname}}
  <h2>Top 10 Most Recent Guestbook Entries</h2>
      {{#each greetings}}
          <br>
           <small>[<i>{{date.ctime}}</i>]</small>
           <b>
             {{#if author}}
               <code>{{author.nickname}}</code>
             {{else}}
               <i>anonymous</i>
             {{/if}}
          </b>
          wrote:
        {{comment}}
      {{/each}}
 </script>
 <div id="comment_content"> </div>
 <form id="comments" action="">
    <div><textarea id="comment" name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
    <div><input id="comment_button" type="button"  value="submit"></div>
 </form>
 <a href="{{ url }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>
```

and here is the JS code:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var source   = $("#entry-template");
      var srcHTML =source.html();    
      var template = Handlebars.compile(srcHTML);
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
      $("#comment_button").click(function(event) {

          var data = JSON.stringify({
            "login": "/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/show",
            "logout": "/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/show&action=Logout",
            "user": {
              "nickname": "dummy",
              "email": "dummy@me.com"
            },
          "greetings": [
          {
            "comment": "COMMENT1",
            "date": {
                "ctime": "Sun Feb 10 23:20:21 2013"
            },
            "author": {
                "nickname": "dummy",
                "email": "dummy@me.com"
            }
          }
        ]
      })
      var html = template(data);
      console.log(html);
      $("#comment_content").html(html);
      });
   });
 </script>
```

Here is how I am referencing Handlebar source

```
Can someone please help?
```

Thanks a mil

Answer (score 0):

Your big problem is that you're using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to prepare your data for the compiled template function:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ ... });
var html = template(data);
```

That will end up handing the `template` function a string (which is a JSON representation of the data you want) when it wants just the object. Drop the `JSON.stringify` and things will start behaving better:

```
var data = { ... };
var html = template(data);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Axmbd/

Also, this part of your HTML:

```
<a href="{{ url }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>
```

doesn't appear to be inside the template's `<script>` so the `{{url}}` and `{{url_linktext}}` won't be filled in. You can fix that by moving that `<a>` to the right place.